# Set cell value depending on another values in editable DevExpress table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress

I use React with DevExpress. In my [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-react-grid-for-material-ui-sgber) I have an editable `Data Grid`, which contains 4 columns: `'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Sum'`.
My goal is to set value of `'Sum'` cell, depending on the values of three previous cells (`'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'`). `'Sum'` value should be a result of `'Value1' + 'Value2' + 'Value3'`.
For example, if:

```
'Value1' = 1;
'Value2' = 2;
'Value3' = 3;
```

value of `'Sum'` should be `6`.
But at the same time field `'Sum'` should be available for editing. So `'Sum' = 'Value1' + 'Value2' + 'Value3'` only if `'Sum'` cell is empty. Otherwise `'Sum'` value should be what user typed on keyboard.
I tried to do it several hours, but with no luck. Is it possible to do it with devExpress?

Comment: @LorenzoCovarrubias it was 4 years ago so I can't remember sorry. But if I didn't reply here it probably means that no solution was found.